# mysql select all rows with same value in two columns

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables in MySQL:

Table1:
cname
a
b
f

Table2:
character | account
a | 1
b | 2
c | 3
d | 4
e | 5
f | 6
g | 7

I want to select all accounts from two tables which cname = character

I've tried this:
`SELECT account FROM table1,table2 WHERE cname = character`

But it returns empty. I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Now something really strange. I've tested it on SQL Fiddle, it works perfectly, but not in my real database. Additionally, SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cname = 'a' returns an empty set...

Comment: Perhaps there are blank characters in one or other of the columns.

Comment: Note also that both you and Dipesh are wrong. `character` is a reserved word in MySQL. So this query won't work at all, hence why no results are returned.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify your table name into query.

```
SELECT account FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.cname = table2.character
```

**OR**

Use `JOINS`

```
SELECT table2.account FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.cname = table2.character
```

Comment: It still returns an empty set.

Comment: @l3utterfly can you please create fiddle at [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so i can have better idea.

Comment: Ok, building it now. FYI, using the second query you suggested returns everything from table2

Comment: @l3utterfly so does not it that you wanted.?

Comment: Sorry, the question was wrong. I've edited it. I've built the database in SQL Fiddle and your script works perfectly... but why doesn't it work in my real database?

Comment: @l3utterfly make sure you are selected correct database...also make sure selected database table has record...and also check for the tables name and datatype you have used on fiddle and on real database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36219/discussion-between-l3utterfly-and-dipesh-parmar)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your data may have whitespace or any other special character appended or prepended to it. Make sure your data is fine. Better try using trim.